# Custom List View in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer, material-design, custom-lists

I am trying to populate Navigation Drawer with some custom layout. XML file for that layout is below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true">

    </FrameLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40px"
            android:layout_marginTop="40px">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgUser"
                android:src="@drawable/empty_profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
                android:layout_marginTop="20px">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="Waqas Ahmed Ansari"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="63km"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Joined: Feb '16"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstDrawerItems"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then I made a CustomAdapter class for `ListView lstDrawerItems`
Here it is.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
Activity activity;
TextView txtFirst;
ImageView imgView;

public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
    super();
    this.activity=activity;
    this.list=list;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_drawer_list, null);

        txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_itemName);
        imgView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById((R.id.drawer_icon));
    }

    HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
    txtFirst.setText(map.get("name"));
    imgView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(map.get("imgDrawerIcon")));
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

When I set list adapter, I am not able to see anything.
I set custom adapter here.
`CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(HomeNoVehicle.this, list);
        ListView drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstDrawerItems);
        drawerList.setAdapter(adapter);`
[image]

But when I set the entries attribute if list, it works well.
[image]
Can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: What kind of methods have you tried(and failed) so far? Also are you just trying to make a list view with a picture and text in every Item?

Comment: I've made CustomAdapter class, inflate custom list view. Tried this method in different ways. Yes, I'm trying to make list view with a picture and text, but Navigation Drawer with custom view

Comment: Try implementing `getCount()` in your BaseAdapter, the Adapter uses that to know what size your data is, if you leave it set to 0 it will never print your list. You can use my code below for reference on how to implement all of the functions of the base adapter in a basic way.

Comment: should be `return list.size();`

Comment: What a foolish mistake! Thank you so much, Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a custom list, the way that I like to start is design the cell, or cells you wish to display in the list. Something maybe like this:

[image: Custom Cell]

Then I like to make a Class to go with that cell:

```
public class ProfileCell extends RelativeLayout {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView name;
    TextView dateJoined;
    TextView distance;

    String nameText;
    String dateJoinedText;
    String distanceText;

    public ProfileCell(Context context) {
        super(context);
        inflate(context, R.layout.nav_list_row, this);
        name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        dateJoined = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date_joined);
        distance = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.distance);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgUser);
        //set Image to a default value
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }
    public String getNameText() {
        return nameText;
    }

    public void setNameText(String nameText) {
        this.nameText = nameText;
        name.setText(nameText);
    }

    public ImageView imageView() {
        return imageView;
    }
    public String getDateJoinedText() {
        return dateJoinedText;
    }

    public void setDateJoinedText(String dateJoinedText) {
        this.dateJoinedText = dateJoinedText;
        dateJoined.setText(dateJoinedText);
    }

    public String getDistanceText() {
        return distanceText;
    }

    public void setDistanceText(String distanceText) {
        this.distanceText = distanceText;
        distance.setText(distanceText);
    }
}
```

Then I also find it convenient to make a class that can hold the information that I want to put in that cell:

```
public class Profile {//Information about Users Profile



    public String name;
    public String dateJoined;
    public String distance;
/////////possibly have image url here ....

    public Profile(String name, String dateJoined, String distance)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.dateJoined = dateJoined;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

}
```

Then I make my custom adapter class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<Profile> profiles;
    Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Profile> profiles)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.profiles = profiles;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return profiles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Profile getItem(int position) {
        return profiles.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            //Custom Cell is inflated inside of the Profile view class
            convertView = new ProfileCell(context);

        }
        ProfileCell cell = (ProfileCell) convertView;
        Profile profile = getItem(position);
        cell.setNameText(profile.name);
        cell.setDateJoinedText(profile.dateJoined);
        cell.setDistanceText(profile.distance);
        //Then you would set the image view to something...
        // cell.imageView().setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        //something like that maybe

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Then if I have set up my list view where I want it, in your case inside a navigation drawer then inside of your navigation activity you can do this:

```
//A list of data to display in list
        ArrayList<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            profiles.add(profile);//Adding same profile over an over
        }

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,profiles);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And then this would display whatever you put in those cells.

I put the full code for this up here:
https://github.com/amffz9/NavigationProject

Comment: The problem is with the `ListView` , last child of `left_drawer`. I'm trying to make this list view a custom one with image and text. Rest is going well

Comment: So has adding a custom adapter like the one in my answer to it not worked? Some slight changes might be necessary to fit your project. What kind of result are you getting with what you are doing? It may be a good idea to add some of your java code to your your question. Put up how you are setting it up on the java side.

Comment: I am editing my question. I'm not able to see `ListView` with custom layout.